# Delphi Invalid Class Typecast

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to build an Delphi class for Invoice, and invoice Lines Array,to export it to JSON , I went to [JSONTODelphi.com](https://jsontodelphi.com) and I extract the class and add it to my project,  but i each time i want to assign a value to (Partner_Shipping_Id) in the class I got "Invalid Class typecast" here my code :

```
unit Quotation;
interface
uses Pkg.Json.DTO, System.Generics.Collections, REST.Json.Types;
{$M+}
type
  TQuotationLines = class
  private
    FDiscount: Integer;
    FPrice: Double;
    FProduct_Id: Integer;
    FQuantity: Integer;
    FTax_Id: Integer;
  published
    property Discount: Integer read FDiscount write FDiscount;
    property Price: Double read FPrice write FPrice;
    property Product_Id: Integer read FProduct_Id write FProduct_Id;
    property Quantity: Integer read FQuantity write FQuantity;
    property Tax_Id: Integer read FTax_Id write FTax_Id;
  end;
  TQuotationInvoice = class(TJsonDTO)
  private
    FCash_Van_Id: Integer;
    FData: TDate;
    FPartner_Id: Integer;
    FPartner_Invoice_Id: Integer;
    FPartner_Shipping_Id: Integer;
    FPricelist_Id: Integer;
    [GenericListReflect]
    FLines: TObjectList<TQuotationLines>;
    [JSONName('lines')]
    FLinesArray: TArray<TQuotationLines>;
    function GetLines: TObjectList<TQuotationLines>;
  published
    property Cash_Van_Id: Integer read FCash_Van_Id write FCash_Van_Id;
    property Data: TDate read FData write FData;
    property Partner_Id: Integer read FPartner_Id write FPartner_Id;
    property Partner_Invoice_Id:Integer read FPartner_Invoice_Id write FPartner_Invoice_Id;
    property Partner_Shipping_Id:Integer read FPartner_Shipping_Id write FPartner_Shipping_Id;
    property Pricelist_Id: Integer read FPricelist_Id write FPricelist_Id;
    property Lines: TObjectList<TQuotationLines> read GetLines;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TQuotationInvoice }

destructor TQuotationInvoice.Destroy;
begin
  GetLines.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TQuotationInvoice.GetLines: TObjectList<TQuotationLines>;
begin
  if not Assigned(FLines) then
  begin
    FLines := TObjectList<TQuotationLines>.Create;
    FLines.AddRange(FLinesArray);
  end;
  Result := FLines;
end;
end.
```

in my from i add in the uses the class name and "Q" is TQuotationInvoice created in Public session , I create this procedure (Below), if i give the (Q.Partner_Shipping_Id) const number like (Q.Partner_Shipping_Id:=1) it work fine but when i pass a variable like (Q.Partner_Shipping_Id:=AshippingID) show error "Invalid Class Typecast"

```
procedure AddQuotation(ApartnerID,AshippingID,APriceListID:Integer);
begin
  Q.Cash_Van_Id:=POSID.ToInteger;
  Q.Data:=Date;
  Q.Partner_Id:=ApartnerID;
  Q.Partner_Shipping_Id:=AshippingID;  // <---------------------- Here the Error 
  Q.Pricelist_Id:=APriceListID;
end;
```

any Ideas ?

Comment: The code you show compile perfectly here with Delphi 10.4.1. So the error is in code you don't show. Please put your AddQuotation to a minimal program with the missing declarations (Q and POSID). In short, edit your question and add a minimal reproducible example. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. BTW: I used https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marlonnardi/JsonToDelphi/master/Pkg.Json.DTO.pas

Comment: You say: *in my from i add in the uses the class name*. Apart from the typos, If that would be true, it should not compile. Anyway, please verify what you have in `uses`. Also show where and how you declare `Q`, and then where and how you assign `Q`.